# Is HttpContext.Current.Items["SameKey"] unique for each call made to the ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, httpcontext

I am using Angular2 as a client and for server side its ASP.NET WebAPI + EF6.
My DbContext is being shared for multiple DB operation within the same WebApi request. To share DbContext among multiple DB Operations, i am keeping DbContext in HttpContext.Current.Items["SameKey"].

So will it be unqiue on each WebApi call?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Item` data is live for single HTTP request/Response. Having said that i wouldnt do what you are doing. Search online for how to have a single dbcontext in a web application and you will find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's guaranteed to be unique. The `HttpContext.Current.Items` is only valid for a single request and when the request is sent back to a browser, its data will be flushed out automatically.

Please visit the following link for more information:

- [When Can We Use HttpContext.Current.Items to Store Data in ASP.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146455/When-can-we-use-HttpContext-Current-Items-to-store)

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

Although I'd recommend you to use an IoC module (e.g. [Ninject](http://mahedee.net/dependency-injection-using-ninject-in-asp-net-mvc/)) to manage the context's lifecycle - Yes `HttpContext.Current.Items[]` is guaranteed to be unique and persisted for the duration of the http request.